# Why does validation loss so much higher than training?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I am trainning a LSTM model that seems to do well on the training set. However, for some reason, after the first few iterations, the validation loss shoots up significantly. I am not even how a loss of 184 is even possible for softmax and cross-entropy loss. Does this look like a bug or expected hehavior?

```
Training for 5 epoch(s)...
Epoch:    1/5     Loss: 5.659843604564667 time_per_batch: 0.024110078811645508
Epoch:    1/5     Loss: 5.194439644813538 time_per_batch: 0.024190187454223633
validation loss: 5.250472049864512
Epoch:    2/5     Loss: 5.014158352967855 time_per_batch: 0.023919343948364258
Epoch:    2/5     Loss: 4.939968596100807 time_per_batch: 0.02540421485900879
validation loss: 5.1598842238623
Epoch:    3/5     Loss: 4.84823331800667 time_per_batch: 0.023817777633666992
Epoch:    3/5     Loss: 4.872153713107109 time_per_batch: 0.023148298263549805
validation loss: 184.54528227306548
Epoch:    4/5     Loss: 4.829729948172698 time_per_batch: 0.023070335388183594
Epoch:    4/5     Loss: 4.780962432026863 time_per_batch: 0.023934125900268555
validation loss: 77.25420267619783
Epoch:    5/5     Loss: 4.766845889671429 time_per_batch: 0.023708105087280273
Epoch:    5/5     Loss: 4.764066659212112 time_per_batch: 0.023237943649291992
validation loss: 435.22167629665796
```

Network Architecture:

```
class RNN(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, vocab_size, output_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, 
             dropout=0.5,
             pretrained_embedding = None):
    """
    Initialize the PyTorch RNN Module
    :param vocab_size: The number of input dimensions of the neural network (the size of the vocabulary)
    :param output_size: The number of output dimensions of the neural network
    :param embedding_dim: The size of embeddings, should you choose to use them        
    :param hidden_dim: The size of the hidden layer outputs
    :param dropout: dropout to add in between LSTM/GRU layers
    """
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    # TODO: Implement function
    self.n_layers = n_layers
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim

    self.embd = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=vocab_size, embedding_dim=embedding_dim)
    if pretrained_embedding is not None:
        nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(torch.from_numpy(pretrained_embedding))
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_dim, num_layers=n_layers, hidden_size=hidden_dim, 
                       dropout=dropout, batch_first=True)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
    self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=hidden_dim)        
    self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_dim, out_features=100)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=100, out_features=output_size)
    # self.logsoftmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

def forward(self, nn_input, hidden, print_shape=False):
    """
    Forward propagation of the neural network
    :param nn_input: The input to the neural network
    :param hidden: The hidden state        
    :return: Two Tensors, the output of the neural network and the latest hidden state
    """
    # TODO: Implement function   
    batch_size = nn_input.size(0)
    if print_shape:
        print(f"vocab_size: {self.vocab_size}, hidden_dim: {self.hidden_dim}, "
              f"nn_input shape: {nn_input.shape}, output_size: {self.output_size}")
        print(f'batch_sz: {batch_size}, embd_dim : {self.embedding_dim}')

    x = self.embd(nn_input.long())
    x, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
    x = x[:,-1,:]

    x = self.bn(x)
    x = self.fc(x)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)
    #x = self.logsoftmax(x)
    # return one batch of output word scores and the hidden state
    return x, hidden


def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
    '''
    Initialize the hidden state of an LSTM/GRU
    :param batch_size: The batch_size of the hidden state
    :return: hidden state of dims (n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim)
    '''
    # Implement function

    # initialize hidden state with zero weights, and move to GPU if available
    weight = next(self.parameters()).data
    #print(weight.shape)

    if (train_on_gpu):
        hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_().cuda(),
              weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_().cuda())
    else:
        hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_(),
                  weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_())
    return hidden
```

Comment: [tag:overfitting]

Comment: Without additional information, I completely agree with @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica : a low training error and a large test error are telltale signs of overfitting : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting